# plotting latex matrix in matplotlib without changing font for rest of figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fonts, latex

I'm trying to plot a matrix in a matplotlib figure. it seems that it requires using tex for all text to make it work.

However when I do this, it changes the fonts of all the rest of the figure. I want to use my regular matplotlib font for everything. I tried to fix it by overriding the font used with `plt.rc("font",**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Arial']})` but it does nto work:

```
plt.figure()
plt.rc("font",**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Arial']})
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
my_matrix = r"$\left(\begin{array}{ll} 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 \end{array} \right)$"
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
plt.title(my_matrix)
plt.show()
```

how can I use tex for the matrix and not change the rest of the fonts set in my matplotlibrc file?